# License Plate Recognition System: Error writing /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf smpt: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pi-4

I faced an error which is Error writing /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf smpt: No such file or directory, when typing

```
root=postman
mailhub=smpt.gmail.com:587
AuthUser=youremail@gmail.com
AuthPass=youremailpassword
FromLineOverride=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

into the raspberry pi based on this tutorial https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/real-time-license-plate-recognition-using-raspberry-pi-and-python , may I know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WJLee9559 the smtp part of the tutorial is only if you want the Raspberry Pi to send you mail. If you do not need that just delete ssmpt and skip to the part with the Python program. If you do need it, the error is telling you that your file does not exist. Try to run `sudo touch /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` then edit it in nano. Don't forget to run `touch` and `nano` as root! Also, did your previous problem with pytesseract get resolved? If you fixed the problem, please close your question.

Comment: *"please close your question"* -> Those are actually distinct separate questions, I've encouraged the OP to do it that way as there will be more people who can answer one or two of them than someone who can answer all three.

Comment: @Quizzer515SY No, the pip install pytesseract have not resolved. And may I know what do you mean by run touch and nano as root?

Comment: Instead of running "touch" or "nano" for the tutorial run "sudo touch" or "sudo nano".